# Stack Overflow flag priority

Tags: support, review, flags, helpful-flags

I started reviewing first posts and late answers. There I flagged some and now I have 7 helpful flags out of 8. The non-helpful flag was my first flag, and it was not a review flag. It was a flag on one of my answers, which had been downvoted out of revenge. I marked it as an "others" flag and in the description I wrote, that this and some other answers have been down voted out of revenge.
Now I wonder: why is this flag still active, while 7 others, which I raised later, are already marked as helpful? Could it be, that other reviewers also flagged the other question/answers so that they got  priority? Or do "others" flags have lower priority then "spam" or "not an answer" flags?

Comment: I also have a custom flag that's still active after 2 days. I guess I'm not alone. :)

Comment: @Mysticial I have _Custom_ flags still active after more than a week.

Comment: @Mysticial exactly one week old flag xD

Comment: I suppose that explains why we're having an election? :D:D:D

Comment: I can see 3 downvotes in quick succession. This is boarderline whether a mod can do anything about it. If they can they may have to get a stack exchange employee to investigate as even mods can't see who voted for who (they can only see patterns). This may explain the time delay

Comment: Some flags are very clear cut what should be done, these also tent to be the most important,  so the first mod that sees them will act.   Other flag that need thinking or experience to deal with, may not be dealt with by the first mod the seas them.

Comment: @RichardTingle yea the flag is exactly about the downvotes. The point is, that the downvoter said in a comment that it was him. So i thought that i flag it as i have a evidence for his incorrect behavior.
But thanks for pinting that out

Comment: Ah, yes, the comment should go heavily in your favour. Even if deleted a mod can still see it

Comment: @RichardTingle thats good to hear. Even if it is only 6 reputation and 3 downvotes. In my opinion thats incorrect behavior and not what this page diserves.

Comment: @RichardTingle, Mystical, devnull: The flag is now marked as helpfull and i got my 6 reputation back. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The posts that you flagged as *Not an Answer* end up in the 10K flag queue where they're reviewed by various members of the site trusted with that privilege. *Spam* flags are given top priority in the moderator queue, as it is often immediately detrimental to the site.

On the other hand, the Moderator Attention / Other flags are handled by moderators after more pressing flags have been dealt with.  Given that the number of moderators is limited, it takes a while for those to be processed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How long do you think it will take, untill my flag is handled? Thanks

Comment: @Springrbua Have patience.  I can't comment on how long it would/might take, but it will get handled _eventually_.

Comment: Okay. Thnaks a lot! +1 and accepted (after 2 minutes :P)

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks!  Who else can fix the technical accuracies better than a diamond mod.

Comment: @devnull Not just a diamond mod, a community manager; even more upgraded

Comment: @RichardTingle I realized that [I spoke too soon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9).

Comment: @devnull I have got my 6 reputation back and the Flag has been marked as helpful. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: @Springrbua Nice! So now you know that custom flags do work, albeit a bit slow :)

Comment: Yea. I think it was just a more or less difficult task, which needs some time to handle.